# Android: SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm building an android app with kotlin. I'm using Firebase Phone Auth. Please help me resolve this error *[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Instantiation of JsonResponse failed! class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaan*.

**One thing to note is that I'm only getting this error when I set minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to true, in both release and debug:**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

I tried pretty much everything I can but all to no avail. I'm forced to not enable minification and resource shrinking.

Comment: Please provide the logcat/snippet

Comment: Alright, just a sec